# Get an input from tkinter and then close the window

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have two python files, one in which i store the code inputData.py and one which is the main file, main_project.py.

In inputData i have this code:

```
class Prompt(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.entry.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        self.inputDt = self.entry.get()
```

In main_project i have this code:

```
from inputData import Prompt
promptData = Prompt()
promptData.mainloop()

class Hearing(object):
    numberBirths = promptData.inputDt
```

What i am trying to do is to assign the value numberBirths the value from the input in tkinter, and after i do that, i need the prompt to close and continue with the rest of the code.
Can you help me with that?

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Comment: @arrethra thank you, i found that before, but i am not that good in programming to find how to implement that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**your entry widget does not have text variable for using get and set function

please add followings before entry and 
edit entry() by inserting textvariable**

```
input_var=0
self.entry = tk.Entry(self,textvariable=input_var)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i appreciate it. My problem is the code stops and doesn't continue to the next step...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.quit()` and `.destroy()` methods:

`inputData.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Prompt(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.answer = None
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.entry.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        self.answer = self.entry.get()
        self.quit()
```

`main_project.py`:

```
from inputData import Prompt

class Hearing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        promptData = Prompt()
        promptData.mainloop()
        promptData.destroy()
        self.numberBirths = promptData.answer
        print("Births:", self.numberBirths)
        # do something else with self.numberBirths

Hearing()
```

Comment: Ehm, the `destroy` command should be included in the method `on_button`. Now it is placed after the `mainloop`, which means it'll never be evaluated because the script gets stuck in the mainloop.

Comment: Really ? I tested it and it worked fine for me. EDIT: @arrethra Nevermind, you are right, I forgot I included a `.quit()` in my code but forgot to put it on the answer.